# Reducing docker image size - /usr/lib, /usr/local and /usr/bin

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to reduce the size of our docker image considerably, as it currently stands at ~1.13GB. Given our app codebase takes up ~300MB and the image is based on Alpine, I think it can be a lot smaller.

I've dug into the image itself, and the largest directories are `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local` and `/usr/bin`. I know that the app itself will have a number of dependencies so I'm sure a lot of these are required but what I'm hoping to find is a way of determining which ones are required, and which ones can be safely removed.

Our app is a Rails app, so hoping there's a way of getting info about these dependencies through bundler or something similar. Any advice would be amazing

Comment: I am no Ruby expert, but you can check here, https://jpetazzo.github.io/2020/03/01/quest-minimal-docker-images-part-2, for some ideas regarding docker images and interpreted languages. In the third part of that blog series, he explains how to use `nixos` to dramatically reduce docker image size, but the process can be a bit complex.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a read through